# How to get Specific Column list from List in Java

Tags: java, list

I have the List from some table and I want Specific Column from that List.

List comes From,

```
List<StockInwordBean> stockInwordList = siDaoImpl.getStockInwordBeans();
```

And it Gets the Result As,(When Printed on Console)

```
[StockInwordBean [srno=2, date=2014-01-16, itemName=666, itemCode=1, metal=Silver, seal=21, itemGroup=21, itemSubGroup=21, variety=21, center=21, quantity=2, weight=1000.0, lessWeight=0.000, addWeight=0.0, recivedTunch=75.00, recivedWastage=10.00, fine=850.0, itemSize=21, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=100.00, recivedMakingAmount=100, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=150.00, saleWastage=5.00], StockInwordBean [srno=3, date=2014-01-16, itemName=121, itemCode=145, metal=Silver, seal=21, itemGroup=21, itemSubGroup=21, variety=21, center=21, quantity=2, weight=12.0, lessWeight=12.000, addWeight=12.0, recivedTunch=1.00, recivedWastage=21.00, fine=21.0, itemSize=21, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=21.00, recivedMakingAmount=2, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=11.00, saleWastage=21.00], StockInwordBean [srno=1, date=2014-01-16, itemName=1, itemCode=188, metal=Fine, seal=21, itemGroup=21, itemSubGroup=212, variety=12, center=1, quantity=21, weight=12.0, lessWeight=21.000, addWeight=21.0, recivedTunch=21.00, recivedWastage=21.00, fine=21.0, itemSize=21, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=12.00, recivedMakingAmount=12, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=21.00, saleWastage=21.00], StockInwordBean [srno=9, date=2014-01-17, itemName=111111, itemCode=45, metal=Patala, seal=54, itemGroup=54, itemSubGroup=5, variety=45, center=45, quantity=45, weight=45.0, lessWeight=45.000, addWeight=45.0, recivedTunch=45.00, recivedWastage=45.00, fine=4.0, itemSize=54, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=54.00, recivedMakingAmount=54, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=545.00, saleWastage=4.00], StockInwordBean [srno=7, date=2014-01-16, itemName=454, itemCode=5, metal=Silver, seal=54, itemGroup=54, itemSubGroup=54, variety=54, center=54, quantity=54, weight=54.0, lessWeight=54.000, addWeight=54.0, recivedTunch=54.00, recivedWastage=54.00, fine=54.0, itemSize=5, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=5.00, recivedMakingAmount=45, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=54.00, saleWastage=45.00], StockInwordBean [srno=4, date=2014-01-16, itemName=54, itemCode=54, metal=Fine, seal=545, itemGroup=4, itemSubGroup=54, variety=54, center=54, quantity=54, weight=54.0, lessWeight=545.000, addWeight=45.0, recivedTunch=45.00, recivedWastage=45.00, fine=4.0, itemSize=545, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=54.00, recivedMakingAmount=54, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=54.00, saleWastage=54.00], StockInwordBean [srno=8, date=2014-01-16, itemName=4, itemCode=5454, metal=Silver, seal=54, itemGroup=45, itemSubGroup=54, variety=54, center=54, quantity=54, weight=5.0, lessWeight=45.000, addWeight=45.0, recivedTunch=4.00, recivedWastage=56.00, fine=6.0, itemSize=546, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=645.00, recivedMakingAmount=64, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=4645.00, saleWastage=6.00], StockInwordBean [srno=6, date=2014-01-16, itemName=656, itemCode=56, metal=Fine, seal=5, itemGroup=65, itemSubGroup=65, variety=65, center=65, quantity=65, weight=65.0, lessWeight=6.000, addWeight=56.0, recivedTunch=56.00, recivedWastage=56.00, fine=5.0, itemSize=65, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=56.00, recivedMakingAmount=5, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=65.00, saleWastage=65.00], StockInwordBean [srno=5, date=2014-01-16, itemName=89, itemCode=8, metal=Fine, seal=98, itemGroup=98, itemSubGroup=98, variety=9, center=89, quantity=89, weight=89.0, lessWeight=89.000, addWeight=8.0, recivedTunch=98.00, recivedWastage=98.00, fine=98.0, itemSize=9, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=98.00, recivedMakingAmount=98, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=9.00, saleWastage=89.00], StockInwordBean [srno=10, date=2014-01-17, itemName=7, itemCode=878, metal=Silver, seal=7, itemGroup=87, itemSubGroup=87, variety=87, center=87, quantity=8, weight=787.0, lessWeight=8.000, addWeight=78.0, recivedTunch=7.00, recivedWastage=87.00, fine=87.0, itemSize=87, recivedMakingChargesBy=Nos, recivedMakingRate=78.00, recivedMakingAmount=7, saleMakingChargesBy=Nos, saleMakingRate=87.00, saleWastage=8.00]]
```

Note : It is simple Array List of type ,

Here  I need only specific list of column as "itemName" form the list.

I have Tried,

```
List<String>  col = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0 ;i< stockInwordList.size();i++)
{
      col.add(stockInwordList.get(i).toString());
      System.out.println("col is.."+col.get(i));

}
```

But it gets list as,(When Printed on Console)

```
col is..StockInwordBean [srno=3, date=2014-01-16, itemName=121, itemCode=145, metal=Silver, seal=21, itemGroup=21, itemSubGroup=21, variety=21, center=21, quantity=2, weight=12.0, lessWeight=12.000, addWeight=12.0, recivedTunch=1.00, recivedWastage=21.00, fine=21.0, itemSize=21, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=21.00, recivedMakingAmount=2, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=11.00, saleWastage=21.00]
col is..StockInwordBean [srno=1, date=2014-01-16, itemName=1, itemCode=188, metal=Fine, seal=21, itemGroup=21, itemSubGroup=212, variety=12, center=1, quantity=21, weight=12.0, lessWeight=21.000, addWeight=21.0, recivedTunch=21.00, recivedWastage=21.00, fine=21.0, itemSize=21, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=12.00, recivedMakingAmount=12, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=21.00, saleWastage=21.00]
col is..StockInwordBean [srno=9, date=2014-01-17, itemName=111111, itemCode=45, metal=Patala, seal=54, itemGroup=54, itemSubGroup=5, variety=45, center=45, quantity=45, weight=45.0, lessWeight=45.000, addWeight=45.0, recivedTunch=45.00, recivedWastage=45.00, fine=4.0, itemSize=54, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=54.00, recivedMakingAmount=54, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=545.00, saleWastage=4.00]
col is..StockInwordBean [srno=7, date=2014-01-16, itemName=454, itemCode=5, metal=Silver, seal=54, itemGroup=54, itemSubGroup=54, variety=54, center=54, quantity=54, weight=54.0, lessWeight=54.000, addWeight=54.0, recivedTunch=54.00, recivedWastage=54.00, fine=54.0, itemSize=5, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=5.00, recivedMakingAmount=45, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=54.00, saleWastage=45.00]
col is..StockInwordBean [srno=4, date=2014-01-16, itemName=54, itemCode=54, metal=Fine, seal=545, itemGroup=4, itemSubGroup=54, variety=54, center=54, quantity=54, weight=54.0, lessWeight=545.000, addWeight=45.0, recivedTunch=45.00, recivedWastage=45.00, fine=4.0, itemSize=545, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=54.00, recivedMakingAmount=54, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=54.00, saleWastage=54.00]
col is..StockInwordBean [srno=8, date=2014-01-16, itemName=4, itemCode=5454, metal=Silver, seal=54, itemGroup=45, itemSubGroup=54, variety=54, center=54, quantity=54, weight=5.0, lessWeight=45.000, addWeight=45.0, recivedTunch=4.00, recivedWastage=56.00, fine=6.0, itemSize=546, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=645.00, recivedMakingAmount=64, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=4645.00, saleWastage=6.00]
col is..StockInwordBean [srno=6, date=2014-01-16, itemName=656, itemCode=56, metal=Fine, seal=5, itemGroup=65, itemSubGroup=65, variety=65, center=65, quantity=65, weight=65.0, lessWeight=6.000, addWeight=56.0, recivedTunch=56.00, recivedWastage=56.00, fine=5.0, itemSize=65, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=56.00, recivedMakingAmount=5, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=65.00, saleWastage=65.00]
col is..StockInwordBean [srno=5, date=2014-01-16, itemName=89, itemCode=8, metal=Fine, seal=98, itemGroup=98, itemSubGroup=98, variety=9, center=89, quantity=89, weight=89.0, lessWeight=89.000, addWeight=8.0, recivedTunch=98.00, recivedWastage=98.00, fine=98.0, itemSize=9, recivedMakingChargesBy=Kg, recivedMakingRate=98.00, recivedMakingAmount=98, saleMakingChargesBy=Kg, saleMakingRate=9.00, saleWastage=89.00]
col is..StockInwordBean [srno=10, date=2014-01-17, itemName=7, itemCode=878, metal=Silver, seal=7, itemGroup=87, itemSubGroup=87, variety=87, center=87, quantity=8, weight=787.0, lessWeight=8.000, addWeight=78.0, recivedTunch=7.00, recivedWastage=87.00, fine=87.0, itemSize=87, recivedMakingChargesBy=Nos, recivedMakingRate=78.00, recivedMakingAmount=7, saleMakingChargesBy=Nos, saleMakingRate=87.00, saleWastage=8.00]
```

So, Please help me to get the list as,

itemName=666

itemName=121

itemName=1
.
.
.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just looping the list containing StockInwordBean  and converting the object to String using toString(). Instead you have to add the specific property from each object to a different List.

Please try this code :

```
List<String>  col = new ArrayList<String>();
for(StockInwordBean si : stockInwordList ){
   col.add(si.getItemName());
}
```

Comment: But here we have to write the function for getItemName().

Comment: in StockInwordBean class or just make the variable public and use directly as si.itemName instead of getItemname(). But better make setter and getter for that variable

Comment: can you please explain me more about(StockInwordBean si : stockInwordList ) , and [si] variable...please..i have not understood the process...

Comment: it is a for-each loop in java.
It means for each StockInwordBean in list stockInwordList. si is the variable for each StockInwordBean object.

Answer (score 1):

you are storing object's tostring not your desired value.

getItemName is getter method.

Try below code snippet.

```
List<String>  col = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0 ;i< stockInwordList.size();i++)
{
      col.add(stockInwordList.get(i).getItemName());
      System.out.println("col is.."+col.get(i));

}
```